# Неверный номер строки в сниппете

Tags: дефект, сниппеты

В сниппетах появилась очень полезная возможность - в случае ошибки отображается соответствующая информация. Но вот только номер строки в ней неверный. Например, я запустил [этот сниппет](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/525159/178988) в FF33, где еще не было `object.assign`:

> ```
> Error: {
>   "message": "TypeError: Object.assign is not a function",
>   "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
>   "lineno": 17,
>   "colno": 68
> }
> ```

Но ошибка не в строке 17, а в строке 6.

Comment: О, там все обращения к консоли и ошибки логируются, я не знал.

Comment: У меня ощущение, что строка считается относительно всего документа HTML, а не содержимого элемента `<script>`.

Comment: @Discord, тогда надо в режиме редактирования сниппета поменять нумерацию строк скрипта на соответствующую?

Comment: не не не, там **все** выводы в консоль теперь выводятся, это устанавливается галочкой _include console×_, кстати пока не переведенной :)

Comment: да, со всеми, это я погорячился :)

Answer (score 6):

Буквально вчера в сниппеты добавили галку *include console*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И теперь вывод вы консоли перехватывается и выводится дополнительно в окне сниппета, поддерживаются следующие функции консоли

- `console.config`
- `console.clear`
- `console.error`
- `console.info`
- `console.warn`
- `console.log`

а так же вывод ошибок.

Для следующего сниппета

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Будет сгенерирован следующий файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из картинки строка приводящая к ошибке действительно имеет номер 12, более того, даже сама консоль показывает, что номер строки 12

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, добавление сниппета не меняет поведение, которое уже есть.

А все это из-за того, что тег скрипт добавлен Inline, а не как файл, а строки считают в том файле, в котором ошибка произошла.

Так что тут два варианта:

- либо статус: так задумано
- либо переделывать сниппет так, чтобы он не вставлял скрипты и css inline

Comment: И ещё вариант: сделать сквозную нумерацию строк, чтобы номер соответствовал номеру в файле.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не, не вариант по-моему, потому что эти четыре окна, на сколько я понимаю, не зависимы друг от друга, то есть ты не можешь сказать с какой строки что будет начинаться

Comment: И что же мешает?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну так а как ты будешь строки считать, если у тебя окна между собой не общаются? :) а конечная генерация вообще по кнопке только происходит

Comment: Ну пообщаются немного.

Comment: @Qwertiy, даже если общаются :-) как ты будешь угадывать величину шапки, которая автоматически генерируется? :)

Comment: Это же константа.

Comment: @Qwertiy, неа, там же еще external Добавляются, плюс какой-нить из скриптов может попробовать добавить тег скрипт вручную

Comment: Где external? Они ж прямо в разметку пишутся и в окне видимы. Если что-то динамически будет меняться, оно ж на нумерацию строк не повлияет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40002/discussion-between-grundy-and-qwertiy).

Comment: *"Как видно из картинки строка приводящая к ошибке действительно имеет номер 12, более того, даже сама консоль показывает, что номер строки 12"* в консоли браузера номер строки - вторичен, потому что при клике на него браузер откроет и покажет нужную строку в файле.

Comment: В консоли сниппета такой возможности нет, поэтому важно выводить правильные номера строк.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, выводить где? в окне редактора или в окне где сама консоль выводится?

Comment: @Grundy лучше бы где консоль. Но можно и в окне редактора - главное чтобы номера строк соответствовали